# Is it possible to connect data from various different layers?

Tags: qgis, layers, biology

I am working on a project estimating the population of a waterfowl. I have point and line data of where I did counts. I also have bathymetric data, data on vegetation cover, outlines of relevant bodies of water, population data of nearest villages, and shapefiles of nearby protected areas, each as a distinct layer. I want to be able to get QGIS to give me the data on the depth, vegetation cover, distance from shore, distance from population centres, and distance from the protected area for each of my points and lines. For lines this would be average for the length of the transects. Is this possible? And if so, how?

Comment: yer its all possible, but your question is pretty high level to try and answer here. might i recommend reading the QGIS training manual to begin with, particularly 'Creating Vector Data and Vector Analysis sections'. https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/index.html

Comment: What you're after is called Multivariate Analysis, a basic example is https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/multi_criteria_overlay.html, that should give you a good primer to start with.